# Making a C program return to the start and ask for input again if a user did not input the right value

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while

it's my first post here so please be gentle to me. I've recently started a C programming class on my university and I got really interested in it. Since I'm working with audio (mixing / mastering music) I decided to try and make a simple program that would calculate the delay times in ms for the user defined BPM (Beats per minute).

What I am currently stuck with is the following: I want the program to return to the start and ask the user to input again if he typed in the wrong BPM (0 in this case).

I tried a **do while loop** however it didn't work quite right, my program would still calculate everything as if a user just typed in 0 and if I typed a correct value it would just loop endlessly.

If I do an **if else statement** it gives the user a message but I'd like to prompt the user for input again together with the message.

I know that this is a pretty simple and basic question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
int main(){

    float BPM;

    printf("Please input the BPM:   ");
    scanf(" %f", &BPM);

    do{

    float HZ = 1000;
    float HZ_Result;
    float BPM_QuarterNote=(60/BPM)*1000;

    float BPM_WholeNote=BPM_QuarterNote*4;
    printf("\n\nDelay time for whole note is: %.2f ms or %.2f Hz", BPM_WholeNote, 1000/BPM_WholeNote);

    float BPM_HalfNote=BPM_QuarterNote*2.0;
    printf("\n\nDelay time for 1/2 note is: %.2f ms or %.2f Hz", BPM_HalfNote, 1000/BPM_HalfNote);

        printf("\n\nDelay time for 1/4 note is: %.2f ms or %.2f Hz", BPM_QuarterNote,  1000/BPM_QuarterNote);

    float BPM_EightNote=BPM_QuarterNote*0.5;
    printf("\n\nDelay time for 1/8 note is: %.2f ms or %.2f Hz", BPM_EightNote, 1000/BPM_EightNote);

    float BPM_SixteenthNote=BPM_QuarterNote*0.25;
    printf("\n\nDelay time for 1/16 note is: %.2f ms or %.2f Hz", BPM_SixteenthNote, 1000/BPM_SixteenthNote);

    float BPM_32ndNote=BPM_QuarterNote*0.125;
    printf("\n\nDelay time for 1/32 note is: %.2f ms or %.2f Hz", BPM_32ndNote, 1000/BPM_32ndNote);


    }while(BPM > 0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show your attempted loop.

Comment: Please also check the return value from `scanf` as well as the scanned input value. If `scanf` does not return `1`, you are testing the *unintialised variable* `BPM`.

Comment: It sounds like you want to put a loop around just the user input part -- the first `printf()` and `scanf()`.

Comment: @kaylum sorry for being slow, I edited the main post to show what I attempted with do while, could you explain me the right way to do it?

Comment: Re your loop edit: the division `60/BPM` will crash because you do it *before* checking if `BPM > 0`.

Comment: You need to put the `scanf` inside the loop. And you need to check the `BPM` value before processing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code below you BPM declaration.

```
do{
    printf("Please input the BPM:   ");
    scanf(" %f", &BPM);
  }while(BPM==0.00);
```

Comment: I suggest avoiding equality tests in floating point, with `while(BPM < 1.0)`

Comment: I did this but I typed while(BPM < 1.0) and it works like I wanted it to. Thank you!

Comment: You could be right depending on the requirement of user...I don't know if negetive values are valid or not in this program.

Comment: BPM = Beats Per Minute.

Comment: Small edit. This is now asking the user to input again if he inserts a value less than 1. I'd like to know if there is a way to add a simple message that would tell the user that he typed in a wrong value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop instead of the if to test for your condition

eg

```
/* while loop execution */
while( BPM == 0 ) {
/* get my input values */
}
```

Comment: Also need to initialise `BPM`.

Comment: In fact `BPM == 0` with a `float` might be undesirable. Why not pick a realistic value such as `BPM < 1.0` but even that would be a dirge ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of a user input loop that exits only when user is satisfied:

```
int main(void)
{
    float fNum= 5.2;
    double dpNum= 5.2;
    long double ldFloat;

    char quit[]={" "};

    while(quit[0] != 'q')
    {
        printf("\n\nEnter a float number: ");
        scanf("%f", &fNum);
        printf("Enter a double precision number: ");
        scanf("%Lf", &ldFloat);
        ... other stuff as needed
        printf("Enter any key to continue or 'q' to exit.");
        scanf("%s", quit);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `float fNum= 5.2;` ? and not double =>>  `5.2`...`dpNum` is not used at all.

Comment: @Michi - LOL, just a cut and paste from some existing code.  They just happened to be there.  The source example cpde actually displayed the `5.2` as a 64 binary.  The short answer, I was lazy.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    printf("Please input the BPM: ");
} while (scanf("%f", &bpm) == 0 || bpm < 0);
```

This loop prints the question until the user inputted a valid floating point number and that said number is at least 0.